# Определение макс. значения и нажатие кнопки в определенном блоке

Tags: javascript

Определение макс. значения и нажатие кнопки в определенном блоке
Здравствуйте. В javascript не очень. Помогите написать скрипт который будет определять максимальное значение из блоков по одному адресу и нажимать кнопку в соответствующем блоке. 
Код одного из блоков:

```
<div class="order">
  <div class="order-ava">
    <img src="/media/images/city/1078.jpg">
      <div class="special-order-ava-2"></div>
        <div class="special-order">
          <span><a href="/page/orders">Халтура</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="details">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>0.86 руб.</b>//значение которое нужно сравнить с другими блоками
            / 1 ч. 13 м. 43 с.                      
          </li>

          <li style="font-size: 11px;">
                            Весны 28 / Восточный Пер 38                                                       </li>
          <li>
            Уровень такси <b>2</b>
          </li>
            <li style="color:green;font-size: 12px;">
                                1 ч. 5 м. 14 с. (-11.5%)
            </li>
        </ul>
          <div class="acceptorder">
            <button class="button_gray" data-id="17279703">Взять заказ</button> //кнопка которую нужно нажать если значение в блоке максимальное
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

таких блоков на странице 20

Comment: Простите, а чего максимальное значение?

Comment: @Yuri Здравствуйте

Comment: @tCode, понял :D

Comment: спс. Сейчас опробую.

Comment: работает., Простите за наглость, а можно еще чтобы скрипт выбирал чтобы имя блока было именно ".order"  а не .order*

Comment: Если Вы хотите что-то уточнить - не правьте чужие сообщения, а добавьте к ним комментарий.

Comment: @Санёк, в каком смысле выбирал имя?

Comment: нужно чтобы он не нажимал кнопку на блоках типа: <div class="order hackwork-order-wrapper">

Comment: Простите за навязчивость, вы мне поможете или мне дальше идти искать?

Comment: @Санёк, смотрите мой ответ. Я изменил его

Comment: Ок. Огромное вам спасибо. Хотел бы так разбираться как и вы, где обучались если не секрет и долго ли?

Comment: и еще вопрос на последок )  как сделать так чтобы после нажатия кнопки скрипт отреагировал на ответ и при необходимости перезапустился?

Comment: <div class="acceptorder"><div class="orderaccepted error" style="">Другой пользователь пытается взять этот заказ...</div></div>  //код появляется вместо кнопки после нажатия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var a = {s: 0, e: ''};
  for(var i = 0; i < $('.order').length; i++){
    if(a.s < parseFloat($('.order').eq(i).find('.details b').text().replace(/\ руб/, ''))){
      a.s = parseFloat($('.order').eq(i).find('.details b').text().replace(/\ руб/, ''));
      a.e = i;
    };
  };
  $('.order').eq(a.e).each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hackwork-order-wrapper')){
      $(this).find('button').click();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="order">
  <div class="order-ava">
    <img src="/media/images/city/1078.jpg">
      <div class="special-order-ava-2"></div>
        <div class="special-order">
          <span><a href="/page/orders">Халтура</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="details">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>0.86 руб.</b>//значение которое нужно сравнить с другими блоками
            / 1 ч. 13 м. 43 с.                      
          </li>

          <li style="font-size: 11px;">
                            Весны 28 / Восточный Пер 38                                                       </li>
          <li>
            Уровень такси <b>2</b>
          </li>
            <li style="color:green;font-size: 12px;">
                                1 ч. 5 м. 14 с. (-11.5%)
            </li>
        </ul>
          <div class="acceptorder">
            <button class="button_gray" data-id="17279703">Взять заказ</button> //кнопка которую нужно нажать если значение в блоке максимальное
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="order hackwork-order-wrapper">
  <div class="order-ava">
    <img src="/media/images/city/1078.jpg">
      <div class="special-order-ava-2"></div>
        <div class="special-order">
          <span><a href="/page/orders">Халтура</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="details">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>1.02 руб.</b>//значение которое нужно сравнить с другими блоками
            / 1 ч. 13 м. 43 с.                      
          </li>

          <li style="font-size: 11px;">
                            Весны 28 / Восточный Пер 38                                                       </li>
          <li>
            Уровень такси <b>2</b>
          </li>
            <li style="color:green;font-size: 12px;">
                                1 ч. 5 м. 14 с. (-11.5%)
            </li>
        </ul>
          <div class="acceptorder">
            <button class="button_gray" data-id="01648932">Взять заказ</button> //кнопка которую нужно нажать если значение в блоке максимальное
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="order">
  <div class="order-ava">
    <img src="/media/images/city/1078.jpg">
      <div class="special-order-ava-2"></div>
        <div class="special-order">
          <span><a href="/page/orders">Халтура</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="details">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <b>0.65 руб.</b>
            / 1 ч. 13 м. 43 с.                      
          </li>

          <li style="font-size: 11px;">
                            Весны 28 / Восточный Пер 38                                                       </li>
          <li>
            Уровень такси <b>2</b>
          </li>
            <li style="color:green;font-size: 12px;">
                                1 ч. 5 м. 14 с. (-11.5%)
            </li>
        </ul>
          <div class="acceptorder">
            <button class="button_gray" data-id="56978678">Взять заказ</button> //кнопка которую нужно нажать если значение в блоке максимальное
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```